# Applying a function to multiple rows of a data frame where the row is an argument in the function in R

Tags: function, dataframe, apply

Apologies for the rather long name, but I wanted to be specific. I am rather new to R and coding so please go easy on me.

I have a function as follows:

```
myfun = function(x, y, g) {return(1 / (1 + exp(y*g%*%x)))}
```

where x is any data frame with n rows and d columns, y is a scalar and integer, and g is a vector of length d (i.e. same as x). I want to run this function for each row of x without using loops.

I have tried various function in the apply family similar to the code below:

```
apply(x = a, 1, myfun(y = 1, g = b)
```

where a is a 3x3 data frame and b is a vector 3 elements long. The above code gives an error that I am missing an argument from myfun, but I am obviously clueless on what to try.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Edit: My actual data frame is huge, sparse, and not very straight forward (I think), so I will include an example data frame and other variables:

```
a = data.frame(c1 = seq(1,3,1), c2 = seq(4,6,1), c3 = seq(7,9,1))
b = c(1,2,3)
c = 1
```

Also, I think I may have not clearly stated an important piece of information. I want to actually do a summation of myfun over all the rows and values of b, so I actually want the following:

```
answer = myfun(a[1,], c, b[1]) + myfun(a[2,], c, b[2]) + myfun(a[3,], c, b[3])
```

In other words, a[1,] should be applied to myfun with b[1] as they are grouped together. I also made an edit to the function above because I forgot to include return(). Hopefully, this makes things more clear. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: It'd be much easier to help you with a bit more context. Could you show your original dataframe, and the expected result?

Comment: @Laurent Apologies for any confusion. I made some edits to my question in response to your comment. Please let me know if those does not help. Thanks!

Comment: You've defined your function with arguments `x, y, z`, but when you call it, you're only specifying `y` and `z` (`myfun(y = 1, g = b)`).